# How to find the right product variant in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a section where I display all the products. I make custom radio buttons for them with product colors and sizes
I display buttons with colors separately - the color is made as a metafield for the product option. And I display the product dimensions separately. When I click on the "Add to cart" button, I need to look for the desired option from the selected color and size. How can i do this? I need to combine two options and find the right one

```js
//How I display radio buttons with colors and sizes  

<div class="variants-picker__list">
        {% assign color_keys = 'Color,color,Colour,colour' | split: ',' %}
        {% for key in color_keys %}
          {% if product.options contains key %}
            {% for color_option in product.options_by_name[key].values %}
              {% for variant in product.variants %}
                {% if variant.options contains color_option %}
                  {% if variant.metafields.custom.color %}
                    {% assign background_style = variant.metafields.custom.color %}
                    {% assign variant_id = variant.id %}
                  {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="{{ product.id }}_card_color"
                id="{{ product.id }}_color_{{ forloop.index }}"
                data-variant-id="{{ variant_id }}"
                style="background: {{ background_style }}; background-size: cover;"
              >
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
          {%- for value in option.values -%}
            {% if option.name == 'Size' %}
              <input
                type="radio"
                id="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
                name="{{ option.name }}"
                value="{{ value | escape }}"
                {% if option.selected_value == value %}
                  checked
                {% endif %}
                {% if option_disabled %}
                  class="disabled"
                {% endif %}
              >
              <label for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                {{ value }}
              </label>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% comment %} {% render 'custom-product-variant-picker', product: product, product_form_id: product_form_id %} {% endcomment %}
      </div>
```